# How to filter zero-prices products in listing page

Tags: magento

I have used the sorting by ->setOrder('price','desc');
but in this case its not working well when we sort the products by name

Is there any way to sort by price (from lower to bigger) in such way, that products with zero price will bein the end of the list???

public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

```
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
       $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection())
             ->setOrder('price','desc');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question not very clear, yet from what I understand:
(Price Sorting) This feature is provided by default in Magento in Product Listing Pages. 
Maybe you have changed the price attribute @ backend.

Check for price attribute.
Used in Product Listing = Yes
Used for Sorting in Product Listing = Yes

Clear Cache, and you should be ready to go.

Comment: no,it will show only the products with the range 0 to 1000
but here i want to show all the products

Comment: The normal sorting works fine (low to high or high to low) but would really like the ability to include the zero price products at the end, an example of how it would be listed would be:

    Product 1: £3

    Product 2: £18

    Product 3: £0

    Product 4: £0

Comment: then create 2 product collections. 1 for greater than 0, and then other for 0 only. Then sort whatever you want independently, and merge the collection just before showing.